# Multiple execSQL() in one function

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I wrote a scheduler app which adds schedule data to a database when the user updates the schedule from the internet using this:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `subject` (`id`, `date`, `start`, `end`, `name`, `room`, `teacher`, `class_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", new String[]{id, date, start, end, name, room, teacher, classId});
```

This is working fine.

However there could be a scenario, that the online schedule will change it's content. Therefore I would write the function like this:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM `subject` WHERE `date` = ? AND `class_id` = ?", new String[] {date, classId});
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `subject` (`id`, `date`, `start`, `end`, `name`, `room`, `teacher`, `class_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", new String[]{id, date, start, end, name, room, teacher, classId});
```

The data is deleted fine, but now not all the content (only one row) is added back in the database. So what I think:

*The delete query is still running while the second insert query is executed too*

So, my question is. How can  I wait until the deletion is finished to add the new data back properly?

Comment: Please, remove the `'` from the field names. They are really unnecessary and make the SQL commands (which you improperly call "queries") hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how `execSQL` calls work; they are always properly serialized.

To update or insert a record, try the update first, and insert only if that record was not found:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(...);
if (sqLiteDatabase.update("subject", cv, "Date = ? AND ClassID = ?",
                          new String[]{ date, classId }) < 1)
    sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow("subject", null, cv);
```

Comment: I understand. However, when a schedule changes, a subject can be removed from the internet. But, it will remain in the database right?

Comment: It is your job to decide how records are identified. I'd guess you'd want to use the ID column instead.

Comment: I agree. But that's why I want to clear that day in the database first, and then load them into it again. (However adding back only one row remains)

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake, I did put the same queries in a while loop. I needed to add the deletion before the while loop which inserted data :3